# Attempt to fill share Twitter link with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter

I have a share link for my Twitter and am attempting to fill the text of the message with dynamic information. In the following example, I want to see "You selected content" in the Tweet box. Here is my jsfiddle. Thanks so much!

https://jsfiddle.net/ksaluja/akotzwop/1/

```
<p><a id="twitterLink" title="Share this on Twitter" class="shareLinksA" href="https://twitter.com/share?url=&amp;text=You selected" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,
      '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600');return false;">Twitter</a></p>
    <div id="content">
    <p>
        Content
    </p>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the content of, well, `#content`. Then you will be able to pass that as a variable in your URL. See my example function:

```js
$('body').on("click", "#twitterLink", function() {
 var content = $('#content').text(),
        twitterShare = 'https://twitter.com/share?url=',
        windowArgs = 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600',
        myURL = '&amp;text=You selected';

    window.open(twitterShare+myURL+content,'Share on Twitter', windowArgs);
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p><a id="twitterLink" title="Share this on Twitter" class="shareLinksA" href="#">Twitter</a></p>

<div id="content">
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/afrvLrzL/3/

Comment: @Kelly Roper I see you tried to edit my code. Please write a comment to clarify first and tell me if my solution is what you are looking for. Of course, you can edit whatever you want to and modify it to your liking.

Comment: Sorry just wanted to remove a URL. I don't know how this process works. Thanks so much for your help and have a great day!

Comment: Oh ok. I removed it. anyway, I'm glad I could help. have a nice day!